# MySQL select from a period of time

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'd like to build a query that updates daily at 1pm, which shows static data from 3pm to 11am nexy day.

if **now is 2018-06-16 12pm**, shows data from  **2018-06-15 3pm - 2018-06-16 11am**

if **now is 2018-06-16 1pm**, shows data from  **2018-06-16 3pm - 2018-06-17 11am**

Here is the query I tried.

UPDATED:

```
SELECT * FROM config WHERE gt BETWEEN CONCAT(curdate(),' 15:00:00') AND CONCAT(curdate()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY,' 10:59:59')
```

ISSUES:

When today is 2018-06-15, curdate() -> 2018-06-15, which shows data of today which no issues.

When today is 2018-06-16, curdate() -> 2018-06-16, which shows data of next day way too early, what i want is update next day 1pm daily.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: more info updated.

Comment: since 3pm to 11am is one continuous series of time, you should be able to just use BETWEEN - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two cases:

1. It's between 0:00 and 12:59: you want yesterday 15:00 till today 11:00
2. It's between 13:00 and 23:59: you want today 15:00 till tomorrow 11:00

The query:

```
select * 
from config 
where
(
  hour(current_time) between 0 and 12 
  and gt >= current_date - interval 9 hours -- yesterday 15:00
  and gt < current_date + interval 11 hours -- today 11:00
)
or
(
  hour(current_time) between 13 and 23
  and gt >= current_date + interval 15 hours -- today 15:00
  and gt < current_date + interval 35 hours -- tomorrow 11:00
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample to build your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE `date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

[Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/) some information on how to work with `INTERVAL`.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886839/how-can-i-run-a-query-in-a-specific-time-using-mysql-or-php) is some useful information how to execute query at a particular time.

EDIT:

> if now() = 2018-06-16 1pm, shows data from 2018-06-16 3pm - 2018-06-17
>   11am

Then you ca use this example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM config 
WHERE DATE(gt) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY_HOUR) AND -- 2018-06-16 3pm
                       DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 22 DAY_HOUR);   -- 2018-06-17 11am
```

DEMO [here](http://rextester.com/RCECN25389)

Note: the first `DATE` should be earlier as second `DATE` in `BETWEEN` statement. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: but it return zero result

Comment: Working now, please check, and example is added

Answer (score 0):

lot of ways you can apply select command. here I mentioned the only 2 ways. this is useful for you.

```
SELECT * FROM config 
WHERE gt BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;


select * from config  where gt  and created_at > (now()- interval 10 day)
```